# Inserting Value into SQL server Database table that contain Trigger with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Actually I use PHP to insert some value into SQL server database table that contain one trigger that i have already created.

any error detected while the execution but I don't find the row.

But if I delete my trigger and I run the program again the row is inserted correctly.

Please help me.

Trigger code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER test6 
ON dbo.test 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
 Select * from dbo.tabletest 
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from 
    -- interfering with SELECT statements. 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

-- Insert statements for trigger here 
END 
GO
```

Comment: can you show the trigger definition ?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER test6
   ON  dbo.test 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 
 Select * from dbo.tabletest
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO

Comment: Could you please add the complete code for trigger in your question. this doesnt provide any useful information.

Comment: check the code again

Comment: this cannot be the complete code , where it says -- insert statement for trigger here , add those actual insert statement in your question.